# Laravel Forge SSL

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, nginx, laravel-forge

I've installed a custom SSL certificate in Forge. Now my site is down -_-.

> Site is not available connection refused

I already restarted my server but nothing works.

This is my `domain.nl` in `etc/nginx/sites-available`:

```sh
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/domain.nl/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain.nl;
    root /home/forge/domain.nl/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.nl/1347/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.nl/1347/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES123428-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA2578786:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB7-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/domain.nl/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.nl-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/domain.nl/after/*;
```

I changed all sensitive information.

Comment: Is the service running? Try testing the configuration with `nginx -t`.

Comment: ```nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful```

Comment: Is your firewall allowing incoming traffic on port 443?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: `netstat -aln | grep 443 | grep -i listen` from the terminal. If there's no output, nothing is listening on that port.

Answer (score 0):

Try restart nginx

service nginx restart

then go to /var/mail and see if there is an error.log file.  Then write tail -100 error.log  to see what the problem is